# Residue of $g(z)$ at z=0 simple pole

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Find the residue of:

$$g(z) = \frac{\psi(-z)}{z(z+1)^2} \space \text{at} \space z = 0$$

### **My Attempt:**

Because $z=0$ is a simple pole, I thought of using the definition.

$$\mathrm{Res} \space _{z=0} g(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z\cdot\psi(-z)}{z(z+1)^2} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\psi(-z)}{(z+1)^2}$$

But as you see: [WolframAlpha Computation](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20z%20approaches%200%20of%20digamma%28-z%29%2F%28z%2B1%29%5E2&x=0&y=0) the limit does **not** exist.

How should I approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say $0$ is a simple pole?

Comment: Oh oh!! didnt notice $\psi(-z)$ it is also  a pole for $\psi(-z)$ right?

Comment: Judging by the link, yes, that's right. But to be honest I don't even know what the digamma is.

Comment: The limits is very hard, I need to post a new question...

Comment: @GitGud: the digamma function is defined as: $$\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in a puntured neighbourhood of the origin:
$$\psi(-x) = \frac{1}{x}-\gamma-\zeta(2) x+\ldots \tag{1}$$
while:
$$\frac{1}{x(x+1)^2} = \frac{1}{x}-2+3 x+\ldots \tag{2}$$
we have:
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{\psi(-z)}{z(z+1)^2},z=0\right) = \color{red}{-(\gamma+2)}.\tag{3}$$
By $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that $z=0$ is a *double* pole for $f(z)=\frac{\psi(-z)}{z(z+1)^2}.$

Comment: Which series is that for $$\frac{1}{x(x+1)^2}$$ Thanks Jack for still helping me! You are a terrific person.

Comment: It is essentially the derivative of the geometric series. Exploit the identity: $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = 1+2z+3z^2+4z^3+\ldots $$

Comment: Hey Jack. So:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n-2} = \frac{1}{x(1-x)^2}$$ 

Let $x \to -x, \therefore$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(-1)^{n-2} x^{n-2} = \frac{1}{x(1+x)^2}$$

Then you are finding the coefficient of what in this?

Comment: @Amad27: exactly, right.

Comment: Thanks Jack, Ill hopefully figure out the rest on my own!

Comment: Jack, I sort of see the tactic. You are finding the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z^2}$ in the digamma, and the coefficient of $z$ in the other part, then you multiply to get the coefficient of **just** $$\frac{1}{z}$$ which is the residue at $z=0$?

Comment: I get it, you multiplied the series and factored out the $$\frac{1}{z}$$ from that. Nice answer!

Comment: Jack, I hope you dont mind, but can you explain the other problem too with the $$(\psi(-z) + \gamma)^2$$ Residue at $z=n$ I really dont know how to! If you can I will be very grateful. Please?