# Difficult Limit involving digamma function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

Evaluate:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \psi(-z)\cdot \bigg (  1 - 2z(z+1)   \bigg) - z\cdot\psi'(-z) $$

If we simply substitute in $0$ that gets us infinity, and problems. The answer is $-2 - \gamma$

How do we solve limits with digamma? Should I use series? Please help! Thanks!

**Full answer is not needed, just a starting point!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can write this limit as a residue, an answer is already given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109040/residue-of-gz-at-z-0-simple-pole/1109069#1109069).

Anyway, since in a punctured neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$ \psi(-x)=\frac{1}{x}-\gamma+\zeta(2)x+\ldots, $$
$$-\psi'(-x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}+\zeta(2)+\ldots,$$
it follows that:
$$ (1-2x(1+x))\,\psi(-x) = -\frac{1}{x}-(2+\gamma)+\left(2+2\gamma+\zeta(2)\right) x+\ldots,$$
so the limit is $-(2+\gamma)$ as wanted.

Comment: You're on fire today!